# Oracle 12c to Oracle 19c Migration - Unusual behavior

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I'm performing test before we migrate Oracle database from 12c to 19c.
I'm facing an unusual behavior, which can be explained with below example.
I've condensed it to reproduceable issue as below.
Sorry for making it very long post, I wanted to feed in all possible information.
If any further information is required, then I would be happy to provide that.

Oracle 12c & 19c versions are as below (from v$instance):

```
VERSION
12.1.0.2.0
VERSION      VERSION_FULL
19.0.0.0.0   19.16.0.0.0
```

**Sample Data**

2 tables are as below
[image: Table 1 - TAB1 data]

[image: Table 2 - TAB2 data]

```
TAB1
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   NULLABLE
COL1    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes
RUL_NO  NUMBER(11,0)    No
INP_DT  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE   No

TAB2
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   NULLABLE
COL1    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No
COL6    NUMBER(11,0)    No
COL7    VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)    Yes
INP_DT  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE   No

Index on TAB2 -
create index tab2_IDX1 on tab2(col6);
create index tab2_IDX2 on tab2(col1);
```

**Problem SQL**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tab1 t
WHERE   (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   tab2 b
                 WHERE  b.col6       = 1088609
                 AND    NVL(t.col1, '<NULL>') = NVL(b.col1, '<NULL>'))
        OR t.col1 IS NULL);
```

This sql returns 10 rows on 12c db, but none on 19c db which is causing regression on 19c side.

Here's the output when this sql is run in trace mode.

**12c Trace**

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> set pagesize 1000
SQL> SELECT  *
FROM    tab1 t
WHERE   (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   tab2 b
                 WHERE  b.col6       = 1088609
                 AND    NVL(t.col1, '<NULL>') = NVL(b.col1, '<NULL>'))
        OR t.col1 IS NULL);
  2    3    4    5    6    7
10 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 572408916

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |           |    10 |   160 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                              |           |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | TAB1      |    10 |   160 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB2      |     1 |    15 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TAB2_IDX3 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("T"."COL1" IS NULL OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "TAB2" "B" WHERE
              "B"."COL1"=NVL(:B1,'<NULL>') AND "B"."COL6"=1088609))
   3 - filter("B"."COL6"=1088609)
   4 - access("B"."COL1"=NVL(:B1,'<NULL>'))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=4)
```

**19c Trace**

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> set pagesize 1000
SQL>
SQL> SELECT  *
FROM    tab1 t
WHERE   (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   tab2 b
                 WHERE  b.col6       = 1088609
                 AND    NVL(t.col1, '<NULL>') = NVL(b.col1, '<NULL>'))
        OR t.col1 IS NULL);
  2    3    4    5    6    7
no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4175419084

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |           |     1 |    31 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI NA                   |           |     1 |    31 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | TAB1      |    10 |   160 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB2      |     1 |    15 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TAB2_IDX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access(NVL("T"."COL1",'<NULL>')="B"."COL1")
   4 - access("B"."COL6"=1088609)

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

Can somebody suggest why this behavior is observed in 19c, as it should return 10 rows like 12c db. It seems **HASH JOIN SEMI NA** step on 19c side is causing this issue, but I can't be sure.
Any help on this matter is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the 2 tables? There are lots of differences in the optimizer between the 2 versions that can lead to this 'bug' (probable bug)

Comment: Added in original post.

Comment: Create table + insert statement with which I'm able to reproduce issue on another 19c db of same version as above.

Comment: create table tab1(
COL1    VARCHAR2(20),
RUL_NO  NUMBER(11,0) not null,
INP_DT  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE   not null);

create table tab2(
COL1    VARCHAR2(20)   not null,
COL6    NUMBER(11,0)   not null,
COL7    VARCHAR2(5),
INP_DT  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE   not null);

Comment: insert into tab1 values('', 957, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 1680, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 1680, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 19941, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 14982, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 14984, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 14981, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 14983, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 5021, localtimestamp);
insert into tab1 values('', 5021, localtimestamp);

insert into tab2 values('PARIS BO', 1088609, '10138', localtimestamp);

Comment: create index tab2_IDX1 on tab2(col6);
create index tab2_IDX2 on tab2(col1);

Comment: What's the output of a simple `select * from tab1 where col1 is null` ? It seems to me that maybe the nulls have been replaced by a blank in the migration procress.

Comment: It returns 10 rows i.e. all rows from tab1.

Comment: try after this:alter session set "_optimizer_null_accepting_semijoin"=false;

Comment: It works with set "_optimizer_null_accepting_semijoin" = false.
Do you foresee any issue if I set this parameter at application level (if at all possible) rather than at session level?

Comment: Thanks gsalem. Appreciate your prompt response on this.

Comment: You hit an (unpublished) bug `21201446 WRONG RESULTS FROM NULL-ACCEPTING HASH SEMI JOIN WITH NVL` - there is a [patch for it](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?requestId=20340825&_afrLoop=276974240460168&patchId=21201446&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=rnfmj4dkh_169), see also example [here](https://hourim.wordpress.com/2017/12/22/null-accepting-semi-join/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 19c execution plan somehow loose the `OR t.col1 IS NULL`  predicate in the Predicate Information

```
1 - access(NVL("T"."COL1",'<NULL>')="B"."COL1")
```

Which is most probably a bug (wrong predicate elimination??).

Anyway a workround (if you can change the query) seems to be to add the `OR` *into the EXISTS subquery*

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tab1 t
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   tab2 b
                 WHERE  b.col6       = 1088609
                 AND    NVL(t.col1, '<NULL>') = NVL(b.col1, '<NULL>')
                 OR t.col1 IS NULL );
```

This also implicitely disables the `NA` semi join back to the `FILTER` plan from 12c, which is an other sign that this is the cause of the wrong behaviour.

Open a `SR` with Oracle for a final solution!

Comment: Thanks for this. It works with the solution suggested by gsalem: alter session set "_optimizer_null_accepting_semijoin"=false; I'm more inclined to alter parameter rather than code.